# Chrome Extension to Resize Window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, window

I am trying to make an insanely simple Chrome extension.  All I want is the following: a "browser_action" toolbar icon that when clicked either does one of the following (either is fine):

- Displays a popup with a link that says "Full Screen" and clicking the link resizes the chrome window to the full size of the screen. (preferable)
- Simply makes the screen full sized by clicking the toolbar icon itself. (still ok)

This should be easy, I've made chrome extensions before but I can't get it to work.  Everytime I try to use the chrome.windows api from either my popup.html, a js included in popup.html, or something similar Chrome simply blocks be from doing anything.  I even tried injecting code into a dummy tab like this:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
var bkg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://www.google.com"}, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "newtab.js"}, function() {
        //Callback
    });
});
```

});

Where `app.js` contains the chrome.windows code to resize the window.  And every time I get nothing.  I have `"permissions" : ["tabs","http://*/*", "https://*/*"]` but I still can't do this very simple task.  Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using Chrome 19, updated to 26 and it works.  Windows API must have been added somewhere in between  Full screen would look something like this (in a background script):

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(wind) {
alert(wind.id);
var maxWidth = window.screen.availWidth;
var maxHeight = window.screen.availHeight;
var updateInfo = {
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: maxWidth,
    height: maxHeight
};
chrome.windows.update(wind.id, updateInfo);});
```